# A Postgresql function stuck in for loop, the query never ends querying

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The function is stuck in for loop, the query remains querying and never ends:

```
ALTER TABLE movement ADD COLUMN bar_id INTEGER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_movement() RETURNS SETOF movement AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
barid INTEGER;
m movement%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 FOR m IN
  SELECT * FROM movement
 LOOP
 barid:= (SELECT bar_id FROM employee WHERE employee_id  = m.employee_id);
  UPDATE movement SET bar_id = barid;
  RETURN NEXT m;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT * FROM get_all_movement();
```

What can i do?

Comment: The @klin reply is perfect. It should be pretty slow, if you update complete table every cycle. Some times can be good to use debug print - RAISE NOTICE statement - to print some message. So you can see so PL function is living still.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need functions and loops for this, the update statement will be simplest and most efficient:

```
update movement m
set bar_id = e.bar_id
from employee e
where m.employee_id = e.employee_id
returning m.*;
```

---

Your function tries to update the whole table in every single step. This may last for hours depending on data amount, not to mention the fact that the result will be incorrect. You have forgotten the `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` statement:

```
...
  UPDATE movement SET bar_id = barid
  WHERE employee_id = m.employee_id;
...
```